# MVC5 SQL LEFT JOIN QUERY

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 tables called Category and Ticket and I want to use these 2 tables which are already in my data base to make my stats table.

I've successfully made the Category column but I don't know how to make my Tickets Issued column work.

My Ticket Issued column is basically categorizing all the tickets into their respective category and making a count of it.

I need help coding in the HomeController so I can link both CategoryID's in both tables together and a bit in About.cshtml to display the table on the About page.

[image]
HomeController.cs <--Need to modify code here

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var data = from category in db.Categories
               group category by category.Title into categoryGroup
               select new CategoryGroup()
               {
                   Title = categoryGroup.Key,
                   CategoryCount = categoryGroup.Count() <-- ***This needs to change into Count of Tickets which have the same category ID***
               };
    return View(data);
}
```

ViewModels\CategoryGroup

```
public class CategoryGroup
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryCount { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

About.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.CategoryGroup>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ticket Statistics";
}

<h2>Ticket Category Statistics</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            Tickets Issued
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)         
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.CategoryCount @*Instead of Category Count I want numbers of tickets that have been issued for certain IDs. *@
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

REFERENCE ONLY

Ticket class

```
public enum Priority
    {
        Low,Med,High
    }

public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; } //A line for our issue like enrollment date in student
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Category Class

```
public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = from category in db.Categories
           select new CategoryGroup()
           {
               CategoryID = category.CategoryID,
               Title = category.Title,
               CategoryCount = category.Tickets.Count()
           };
```

Comment: Well that was easier than I expected! Worked perfectly! One more question: If I were to make more than one table do I have to query all the data in that var data? OR can i make another one named var data2 and return View(data2); right under return View(data);??

Comment: @JasonWan - you can only have one return statement, and there's only one model for the view - so you'd need to have it in the same data variable.

Comment: So the data variable is a space where you can queries a bunch of data like category titles,Ticket priorities or userID then reference it in the About.cshtml to display it?

Comment: @JasonWan - the data variable is the Model for your About.cshtml; the Controller places whatever the View (About.cshtml) needs there. That's ASP.NET MVC in a nutshell. :)